# How to cast to unknown generic runtime type (C# ChangeType equivalent)

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm brand new to Flutter / Dart and I'm trying to build a reusable infinite scroller with placeholder loading. The class is as follows:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PagedScroller<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  final int limit;
  final Future<List<T>> Function(int, int) getDataFunction;
  final Widget Function(T) renderFunction;
  final Widget Function() renderPlaceholderFunction;

  PagedScroller(
      {@required this.limit,
      @required this.getDataFunction,
      @required this.renderFunction,
      @required this.renderPlaceholderFunction});

  @override
  _PagedScrollerState<T> createState() => _PagedScrollerState<T>();
}

class _PagedScrollerState<T> extends State<PagedScroller> {
  int _offset = 0;
  int _lastDataLength = 1; // Init to one so the first call can happen
  List<dynamic> _items = [];
  Future<List<dynamic>> _future;
  bool _isInitializing = false;
  bool _isInitialized = false;
  bool _isLoading = false;
  ScrollController _controller =
      ScrollController(initialScrollOffset: 0.0, keepScrollOffset: true);

  _PagedScrollerState();

  void _init() {
    _isInitializing = true;

    _reset();

    _controller.addListener(() {
      bool loadMore = false;
      if (_controller.position.maxScrollExtent == double.infinity) {
        loadMore = _controller.offset == _controller.position.maxScrollExtent;
      } else {
        loadMore =
            _controller.offset >= _controller.position.maxScrollExtent * 0.85;
      }

      // Only load more if it's not currently loading and we're not on the last page
      // _lastDataLength should be 0 if there are no more pages
      if (loadMore && !_isLoading && _lastDataLength > 0) {
        _offset += widget.limit;
        _load();
      }
    });

    _load();
    _isInitializing = false;
    _isInitialized = true;
  }

  void _reset() {
    // Clear things array and reset inital get-things link (without paging)
    setState(() {
      _future = _clearThings();
    });

    // Reload things
    // Reset to initial GET link
    _offset = 0;
  }

  void _load() {
    setState(() {
      _future = _loadPlaceholders();
      _future = _loadData();
    });
  }

  Future<List<dynamic>> _clearThings() async {
    _items.clear();
    return Future.value(_items);
  }

  Future<List<dynamic>> _loadPlaceholders() async {
    // Add 20 empty placeholders to represent stuff that's currently loading
    for (var i = 0; i < widget.limit; i++) {
      _items.add(_Placeholder());
    }

    return Future.value(_items);
  }

  List<dynamic> _getInitialPlaceholders() {
    var placeholders = List<dynamic>();
    for (var i = 0; i < widget.limit; i++) {
      placeholders.add(_Placeholder());
    }
    return placeholders;
  }

  Future<List<dynamic>> _loadData() async {
    _setLoading(true);

    var data = await widget.getDataFunction(widget.limit, _offset);

    // When loading data is done, remove any placeholders
    _items.removeWhere((item) => item is _Placeholder);

    // If 0 items were returned, it's probably the last page
    _lastDataLength = data.length;

    for (var item in data) {
      _items.add(item);
    }

    _setLoading(false);

    return Future.value(_items);
  }

  void _setLoading(bool isLoading) {
    if (!mounted) {
      return;
    }

    setState(() {
      _isLoading = isLoading;
    });
  }

  Future<void> _refreshThings() async {
    _reset();
    _load();
    return Future;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (!_isInitializing && !_isInitialized) {
      _init();
    }

    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _future,
      initialData: _getInitialPlaceholders(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          List<dynamic> loadedItems = snapshot.data;
          return RefreshIndicator(
            onRefresh: _refreshThings,
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: loadedItems.length,
              controller: _controller,
              physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                var item = loadedItems[index];
                if (item is _Placeholder) {
                  return widget.renderPlaceholderFunction();
                } else if (item is T) {
                  // THIS IS THE LINE THAT FAILS 
                  return widget.renderFunction(item);
                }

                return Text('Unknown item type');
              },
            ),
          );
        }
        return Container();
      },
    );
  }
}

class _Placeholder {}
```

The line that fails above:

```
return widget.renderFunction(item);
```

Fails with the following:

```
type '(MyModel) => Widget' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic) => Widget'
```

I understand why this is happening. The compiler can't know that type T from my `PagedScroller<T>` is the same as type T from `_PagedScrollerState<T>`. As a result, Dart tries to be helpful and converts my callback function of type `Widget Function(T)` to `Widget Function(dynamic)`.

I then figured "maybe I can fake it out" with the following since I know the T in `PagedScroller<T>` and `_PagedScrollerState<T>` are *always* the same:

```
var renderFunction = widget.renderFunction as Widget Function(T);
return renderFunction(item);
```

Interestingly, this gives me a warning:

```
Unnecessary cast.
Try removing the cast.
```

Yet it won't even run that line (crashes) with the following:

```
Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md
```

Changing everything to dynamic works a charm, but I really don't want to lose the readability of generics here if I don't have to.

Despite extensive searching, I can't find the equivalent of C#'s Convert.ChangeType where you can provide types at runtime so I can just do the cast I want and be done with it.

This seems like a really simple thing to achieve, but I'm stuck.

You can consume the scroller with this simple main.dart copy/pasted:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:minimal_repros/paged_scroller.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Future<List<MyModel>> getDataFunction(int limit, int offset) async {
      var myModels = List<MyModel>();

      // Simulate API call
      await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 1000));

      for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        var myModel = MyModel();
        myModel.count = i + offset;
        myModel.firstName = 'Bob';
        myModels.add(myModel);
      }

      return myModels;
    }

    Widget renderFunction(MyModel myModel) {
      return Text(myModel.firstName);
    }

    Widget renderPlaceholderFunction() {
      return Text('Loading');
    }

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: PagedScroller(
            getDataFunction: getDataFunction,
            renderFunction: renderFunction,
            renderPlaceholderFunction: renderPlaceholderFunction,
            limit: 20));
  }
}

class MyModel {
  int count;
  String firstName;
}
```

Comment: So much source code. Is all this source code really necessary to understand the meaning of the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the declaration of your `State` class, you forgot to specify the generic parameter of the widget.

Instead of:

```dart
class _PagedScrollerState<T> extends State<PagedScroller> {
```

do:

```dart
class _PagedScrollerState<T> extends State<PagedScroller<T>> {
```

Comment: Don't! We're human :). But consider disabling `implicit-dynamic` in your `analysis_options.yaml`

Comment: I wasn't aware of this. Wish it was a default